# Is it appropriate to ask a question about how to store and structure JS files?

Tags: discussion, questions, scope

Since it's not simple to search for this question on Google, I would like to ask here, on Stack Overflow, what to do with JS files.

I have many JS files in my project, each file has at most 2 functions. For example when somebody opens an 'order' page, the AJAX fills the fields with data. Is it appropriate to put all those files into one and all `$(document).ready` merge into one? What if I use the same name of the field in two different htmls? Etc.

Is it a good question or should I post on Programmers or what?

Comment: It sounds like it would be opinion based on here

Comment: Just to note: merging (and probably minifying) is something you generally do when you create a deployable version of the application - and there is plenty of standard tooling that can do it for you automagically. I hope you're not going to do this directly in your source code and make it exceptionally hard to maintain.

Comment: So, I searched for "how to store and structure js files" and got about 11 million results. The first result was to [a Stack Overflow question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/752198/215552) (which incidentally should be closed). Another was on [programmers.se](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/q/270723/222246) Please do actually try searching before even thinking about asking on SO.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - I think you misread the tooltip for opinion based. *Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience*. That applies here. There are not so many opinions that things get wildly out of hand, and there is no need to be over zealous towards questions which are more than simple debug my code or write my feature.

Comment: @TravisJ Sorry, what? I didn't say anything about opinion-based in my comment... If you're talking about my vote on the linked SO question, it is very much off topic. If you'd prefer me to use "too broad" I can do that. It's basically asking how to structure files in a web application, which is different for every framework/company/person. I would say that I'm an expert, and my experience is that there is no correct answer to the question, only opinions.

Comment: @TravisJ Of course, you're welcome to disagree, and vote to reopen, as I expect you have.

Comment: When you, for example, link to a question and note that it should be closed here, that is essentially invoking the meta effect on that question as you have led other users from here to close the question. While you did not directly say "opinion-based" in your comment, the vote there coupled with the guided statement "should be closed" may as well have.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan - With regards to "there are only opinions" for how to combine or structure js files to avoid excessive server requests, it may be true that there is not *one* perfect answer, but that does not mean that there are no answers or that every answer is pure opinion without any actual expertise involved.

Comment: The question in the linked post is not "how to combine or structure js files to avoid excessive server requests". They are "Is the best way to use include files .. with the extension .JS? Anything else or better with respect to this? ..should i be using the same for my .js files? Anyone have some recommendation on directory structure?" "best", "anything else", "better", "should I", "recommendation"... How are those questions *not* likely to solicit opinions?

Comment: 2009 greatly varies from today. Should you ask that question now? No. Should that question be treated as if it were asked today? Perhaps this is where we have a disagreement.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you're going to ask a 'best practice' type of question. This type of question is generally not well-received on *any* Stack Exchange site, for reasons described [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/142353/why-is-asking-a-question-on-best-practice-a-bad-thing). My first guess for this particular question would be Programmers, but [apparently](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6967/best-practices-bad-patterns-good) they don't like best practice questions as well.

Comment: [Progs meta discussion](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6967/31260) you refer to has been sort of superseded by a newer one: [Making “best practices” questions more palatable: how to ask a “best practice” question that is acceptable to the community?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/7091/31260)

Comment: This isn't some sort of broad "best practice" topic though. It is rather well defined, and there are definitely industry standards for how to manage disjoint JavaScript files (for example, Angular both creates and solves this problem).

Answer (score 0):

As long as you address the core issue you are facing with an example that is either reproducible or in depth enough to envision it should be on topic here.

For example, the main problem with using many (more than a few) js files is the server load for so many requests, and also the disjoint feeling that having a bunch of these files in different locations can produce.

Once you have identified which specific aspect of these is actually causing a problem, if you are able to lay out the cause, the solution you are trying, and why it did not work (or what happened that you did not expect), then that should be a viable question.

If you are unable to produce a narrowed version then your question will most likely not be well received so make sure that you do not phrase it broadly or in a way that could be answered as a long list of options (i.e. A: Well, you could do this, or this, or this, or this, etc.).

Just make sure to give a good example of your situation (without being too verbose) so that the question can actually be answered. A good outlook for doing this can be found here: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/